# how do I restore the last ListFragment from the current Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listfragment, fragmentmanager, fragment-backstack

My app has structure like this

**MainActivity** extends ActionBarActivity *-- on button press ->* **ListFragment** --*on list item press*--> **Fragment**

When in  **Fragment** and if back key is pressed it goes to **MainActivity**  directly . How do I make it to go to the ListFragment

Following is what I expect it to do

**Fragment** *----on back key pressed-->***ListFragment** *--on Back Key pressed --->* **MainActivity** extends ActionBarActivity

Following code is what I am using in mainactivity and listfragment to start any fragment

```
.........................................

             case 5:

           fragment = new HomeFragment();       
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            //getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            //setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
```

**UPDATE**

Now I have added the following code to my MainActivity

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

       Fragment frag = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frame_container);

       if((frag instanceof CommonMasjidPrayerTimes)) {
            finish();
        }
}
```

And following code to my listfragment

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();


                                //  fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
                            if (masjidNamazTimings != null) {
                                    FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                                    ft.addToBackStack(null);
                                    ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, masjidNamazTimings).commit();

                            }
```

Now when I press the backbutton on my list fragment or fragment it doesnt go back

Comment: Are you using `FragmentTransaction` with proper `replace`/`addToBackStack`/`hide`? perhaps paste some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should look like this:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
ft.addToBackStack(null);
```

Try this. This will work.

Comment: Do I need to put this in the ListFragment too ?

Comment: you need to use `ft.addToBackStack(null)` for every `Fragment` you want to add to the backstack ... if you dont call `ft.addToBackStack(null)` for a certain `Fragment` it wont be added to the backstack.

Comment: FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
ft.addToBackStack(null);ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this missing: `.addToBackStack(null)`?
See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#addToBackStack%28java.lang.String%29)